# How do I give a list dynamically without hardcoding to MongoDB's $in?

Tags: perl, mongodb-query

I have a list of ids that I want to search in the mongoDB collection.

Below code works fine, but there are multiple DB calls for each id and I cannot pass an array list without hardcoding.

```
$db->$collection->find( {
"_id" => { 
    '$in' => [ MongoDB::OID->new( value => "56de679ce64cfa37a61b94f3" ), 
               MongoDB::OID->new( value => "56d533dee64cfa2a970b2631" )
             ]
         } 
} );
```

But I want to pass the ids dynamically, something like this

```
$db->$collection->find( {
    "_id" => { 
               '$in' => [  @list   ]
             } 
 } );
```

Where @list contains two elements:

```
[
  '56de679ce64cfa37a61b94f3',
  '56d533dee64cfa2a970b2631'
]
```

How can I make this work by passing a dynamic array of ids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those things in the array ref need to be MongoDB::OID objects, you need to create those.

You can use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) to do that dynamically. It's like a `foreach` loop. You should be familiar with it as the *map* in _map_reduce in MongoDB is the same thing. The iterator variable in Perl is `$_`.

```
my @list = (
  '56de679ce64cfa37a61b94f3',
  '56d533dee64cfa2a970b2631',
);

$db->$collection->find( {
    "_id" => { 
               '$in' => [  map { MongoDB::OID->new( value => $_ ) } @list   ]
             } 
 } );
```

Comment: Thanks that works !!, I feel for every run of MongoDB::OID->new( value => $_ ) there is a DB call. I was looking for something with a single DB call to fetch the information. Is that possible?

Comment: @Babu I have no idea I'm afraid. Never used MongoDB. You would need to check the documentation or read the code (you can do that at metacpan.org). Otherwise, please ask a new question as that changes the question of this one considerably.

Comment: Anyways thanks for your quick help, this solves my immediate problem :-)

Comment: Actually, I just checked [the code of MongoDB::OID](https://metacpan.org/source/MONGODB/MongoDB-v1.2.3/lib/MongoDB/OID.pm#L47). There certainly is no DB call. It just creates a random OID if there is none given.

Comment: Also check https://metacpan.org/source/MONGODB/MongoDB-v1.2.3/lib/MongoDB/OID.pm#L131 and just use the same thing in your `'$in'` to avoid the object. That way you can monitor if there really is a call to the DB. Something like `[ map { { '$oid' => $_ } } @list ]`.

Comment: @BabuPrasad and welcome to Stack Overlfow and the Perl tag, by the way. Make sure to at least take the [tour] so you learn how to use this platform and how to accept helpful answers. :)